# VersionControlServer - Get latest version of file at a specific date/time

Tags: c#, version-control, tfs, download, timestamp

I have a program gets the latest version of files from a TFS server using the following code.

```
TeamFoundationServer myTFS = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer(myURL);
VersionControlServer myVCS = (VersionControlServer)myTFS .GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

ItemSet downloadItems = myVCS.GetItems(myDirectory, RecursionType.Full);
foreach (Item item in downloadItems.Items)
{
    item.DownloadFile(myDownloadPath);
}
```

Instead of getting the latest version, I would like to be able to specify a date and time, and get the ItemSet of items at that point in time.  Then, on the DownloadFile call, I want to get whatever was the latest version of the files in the ItemSet at the specified date and time.

I see that Item has a CheckinDate property, but if this value is after the date and time that I am looking for, I am not sure how to get the previous version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you query items with [`GetItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.getitems%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), you should provide the version spec you're interested in, in this case a [`DateVersionSpec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.dateversionspec%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

For example:

```
DateTime whenever = DateTime.Now;
ItemSet downloadItems = myVCS.GetItems(myDirectory, new DateVersionSpec(whenever), RecursionType.Full);
```

Obviously replacing `DateTime.Now` with whatever you're interested in.