# How to download previous version on file at TFS 2013?

Tags: c#, version-control, tfs

I want to download previous version of source code at TFS 2013.

I can get latest version:

```
String repositoryPath = "$/MyColl1/Folder1/Folder2/TargetFile.txt";
String localPathStored = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/" + "TargetFile.txt";
String uriSite = "http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/../../vN.0/....asmx";
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection =TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(uriSite));

VersionControlServer versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
versionControlServer.DownloadFile(repositoryPath, localPathStored);
```

But how to get previous version?

Answer (score 2):

Easy.

With [VersionControlServer.GetItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138927.aspx) you get the metadata for the file/folder version you are interested in; then call [DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138502.aspx) on it do get the content.

There are many overloads so you can choose the best for you scenario.

You can see an example at [Get latest version of file at a specific date/time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931114/versioncontrolserver-get-latest-version-of-file-at-a-specific-date-time)